# Django REGEX --How To Replace %20 In URL?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create some nice looking permalinks for my DJANGO site.  Specifically for a product page, i want it to appear in browswer as product/product-title

so if I have a product with the title of "Free $20 Coupon With Purchase"

the permalink would show as product/free-$20-coupon-with-purchase

my url is as follows:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$', product_by_detail, name='product_detail')
```

but in the browser the URL is appearing as

product/free%20$20%20Salad%20Coupon%20With%20Purchase

i know the %20 represents the space, but is there something i can do in the regex to replace the %20 with a '-' character?

Comment: The browser URL has nothing to do with Django, it's just based on how you typed things into the address bar. If you want to handle that with Django then you would have to issue a redirect whenever people go to that site to a similar URL with dashes instead of spaces.

Comment: Well, this isn't a job for the regex in the URL pattern. That just determines what characters are *expected*. You need to fix this in whatever template code is generating the link to that URL in the first place.

Comment: okay--so i guess maybe in the view that I have which generates the template, i would need to strip out the spaces there maybe?

Comment: Really you should consider having a separate slug, similar to how this question has "django-regex-how-to-replace-20-in-url". Django makes that easy with [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#slugfield).

Comment: ok i will go that route--thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is by generating an actual slug for the model using a `SlugField`. If there's spaces in it, it's not a slug!.

On your model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

And if you're adding those items in the admin panel, you can generate the slugs as a user types using the `prepopulated_fields` attribute of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

This will create a slug from the `title` as a user types.

*Note: The `SlugField` will also likely strip out the `$` character.*